# Installshield - How can I overwrite HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry?

Tags: windows, installshield

I tried to change this reg key (and subkey, value) `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone` in both hives, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

[image]

Even when using the same method, I can only overwrite this key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.
On `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, I can overwrite subkey but cant change this `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone` reg value!

Setup.exe require Administrator Excution level already...

What is happening and how can I make it work?

ACL info:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone
Owner  : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Group  : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Access : BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadKey
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  -2147483648
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  268435456
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  268435456
         CREATOR OWNER Allow  268435456
         APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  ReadKey
         APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  -2147483648
         S-1-15-3-1024-1065365936-1281604716-3511738428-1654721687-432734479-3232135806-4053264122-3456934681 Allow  ReadKey
         S-1-15-3-1024-1065365936-1281604716-3511738428-1654721687-432734479-3232135806-4053264122-3456934681 Allow  -2147483648
```

Comment: Have you checked the ACL of the key you can't write to?

Comment: Your installer is broken by design if you need to write to both HKCU and HKLM.

Comment: @Anders I updated ACL info for this key already, but since installer run as admin already, I cant figure out why and how tho make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CapabilityAccessManager ConsentStore is by user, you couldn't do something similar not even importing a reg file in `regedit` after an UAC consent, because the path it is owned by `SYSTEM`.

It is for security reason. To do something similar you should compromise the default ownership of the path.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is very helpful! However, can I alternate the default ownership of the reg using this MSI package? config or script?

Comment: You could make the path owned by the administrator user rather than SYSTEM launching a script that change the ownership using ACL commands, but you shouldn't in first place, this can be identified as illegit procedure by antimalware software and anyway it isn't granted that adding keys that aren't even supposed to be searched in that register path will work.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I know the procedure is illegit but the customer requires me to do this. I'll try to convince the customer to use another method that does not violate windows privacy's policy. Else, I will use your advice! Many thanks